# Spring Webflux Callable not working for async

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

```
package demo;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@EnableAsync
public class DemoApplication {
    @RestController
    public static class MyController {
        @GetMapping("/callable")
        public Callable<String> callable() throws InterruptedException {
            log.info("callable");
            return ()-> {
                log.info("async");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                return "hello";
            };
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The code above is the spring project code.
I predicted that when http:localhost:8080/callable is called, "Hello" will be output in 2 seconds, but {} will be output.
In my console printed "Callable" but not printed "Async" Plz help me why my code not work??

i add my pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Note that `@EnableAsync` is meant to set up support for `@Async` annotated methods. It’s not clear if you thought it would somehow help with your handler method.

Comment: It may be worth having a read through the webflux reference documentation - 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#spring-webflux

Answer (score 0):

WebFlux expects a Publisher(Mono/Flux) to be returned by the Controller. You can create a `Mono` by providing a `Callable` like this:

```
@GetMapping("/callable")
public Mono<String> callable() throws InterruptedException {
    log.info("callable");
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        log.info("async");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return "hello";
    });
}
```

As a side note, `Thread.sleep` should never be used within a reactive pipeline in actual application code.

Comment: sleeping a thread in a Mono.fromCallable is extremly dangerous, blocking and will block the event loop crippling the application performance hard. Blocking calls should be placed on own scheduler to guarantee not interrupting the non/blocking parts of the application. Downvoted.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Read the question again. It's about the Callable. `sleep` is there for test purposes only. Don't downvote for no reason, please.

Comment: the solution to the question is dangerous and can give serious implications to the ones implementing it. That is a very valid reason, the info logging says "async". `Thread.sleep` blocks, that is a very big difference.

Comment: @Toerktumlare These lines come from the question and  they have nothing to do with the answer. I've also add a side note for that.